# What is the pH of CsBr?

Tags: acid-base, ph

> What is the pH of CsBr?
>
> 1. 3.8
> 2. 7
> 3. 9
> 4. 12

According to me,

$\ce{Cs+ + H2O <<=> CsOH + H+}$   (because $\ce{CsOH}$ is a strong base, the forward reaction should not occur, right?)

$\ce{Br- + H2O <<=> HBr + OH-}$ (because $\ce{HBr}$ is an acid, the forward reaction should also not occur, right?)

So the answer should be $\mathrm{pH} = 7$.

Comment: There's always equilibrium constant for such reactions, but your reasoning is otherwise OK

Comment: If there was an equilibrium constant present, how would this change/affect the answer?

Comment: Both CsOH and HBr are soluble strong (base/acid) which helps explain the relative lack of effect. In aqueous solution anyway, the effect would be very small

Answer (score 3):

The reactions you have shown could in fact occur (in the forward direction) to a slight degree in a solution of cesium bromide in water. But I would expect them to occur to a lesser degree than the autoprotolysis of water (formation of hydronium and hydroxide ions from two water molecules), so their effect on pH would be insignificant, and the pH would effectively be neutral.